# javascript removing meta tags that's added with document.createRange().createContextualFragment() from the </head>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my react `componentDidMount` I get meta tags from the response that needs to be added before the `</head>`. The problem is that I need to remove the meta tags when the component unmounts. I saw a solution to add an ID so I can do getElementById and remove it that way but since the meta tags are dynamic unless the person adding them in the response adds them manually it won't work for this case. Is there a way to do this?

```
  componentDidMount() {

    if (this.props.headerContent {
return window.document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.props.headerContent);
    }
}
```

The sample response can be something like this

```
<meta name=test123> <meta name=test242>
```

this requires a node to work unfortunately

```
      window.document.head.removeChild();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createContextualFragment()` is creating a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Before you return it from `componentDidMount()` you could loop over its `.children` and either add an attribute like a `class` you can later look up, or just store a reference to those nodes somewhere so you can later remove them.

For example (not tested):

```js
// in componentDidMount
const fragment = window.document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.props.headerContent);
for (const child of fragment.children) {
  child.classList.add('managed');
}

// in componentWillUnmount
window.document.head.querySelectorAll('.managed')
  .forEach((node) => node.parentElement.removeChild(node));
```

Instead of using classes you could do something like (also untested):

```js
// in constructor
this.managedHeadNodes = [];

// in componentDidMount
const fragment = window.document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.props.headerContent);
this.managedHeadNodes.push(...fragment.children);

// in componentWillUnmount
this.managedHeadNodes.forEach((node) => node.parentElement.removeChild(node));
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to loop over its `.children` or storing a reference to those nodes?

Comment: @steven5210 I updated my original answer with a couple of examples

Comment: @steven5210 you may also want to look into libraries like `react-head` and `react-helmet` which might help you to achieve what you’re looking for in a more React-y way.

Comment: thanks for giving me examples for both! I decided to go with the node approach. It looks like your untested examples are too good because they both worked.

Libraries would be good but they don't like us using 3rd party libraries unless it's necessary.